# Play a file while recording using an HTML 5 player

Tags: angular, nginx, html5-video, mp4

Hy to everybody
Hope someone can help me on this..
I have a nginx server who is now showing mp4 files in a website on an html5 player. Evertything fine but i have some file very long( 3-4 hours) and i should show them where they are still in recording.

What is the correct approach to solve this? 
We are studing webRTC but is seems complex for the target we have: "show files while they  are still in recording..“ 
Regards 
Daniele

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this problem.  The easiest is to use an HLS encoder, where the recording is written to segment files as it goes.  The client can easily request whatever segment it wants.

If you absolutely cannot change the way you're recording now, a hacky alternative is that you DIY this with ranged requests.  This assumes that your server will serve an incomplete resource, that you don't care about caching, and that you want to make your own Media Source on the client.  Use MediaSource Extensions for this, but I don't recommend it.

Comment: Well, use HLS ia interesting optio , but it s good for making a playback of a stream.. Here i would like the user can go forward and back in the piece of file that has already been recorder. Is it possible with hls?

Comment: @DanieleSaretta Yes, this is possible with HLS.

Comment: Do you have an idea where i can found an example? I would like to explore this possibility...

Comment: There might be a better tutorial somewhere, but there's a basic code sample here for getting started on the client-side:  https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/

Comment: Sorry Brad for bothering you again, I tried to do as suggested but i had to stop because my NGINX server does't do HLS for VOD... I asked a quotation for NGINX plus , but, in the mean while... Do you know if we can achive same features using VOD MP4 feature present in basic NGINX server?

Comment: Well, directly transcode content in m3u8 is the solution :-)